# A child table reference parent table which has FK from a grandparent table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

So I have something like a table call People, then I use an isA relationship to branch out into Professor and Student. Of course I have fk of student and prof references to People. Now I want to make another isA relationship which branched out from Student, 2 tables, call non-GTA and GTA. Then my fk in these 2 going to reference to People or Student? I mean can i reference a FK to a FK?

Here is my attempt

```
create table People
(name varchar(50),
ssn varchar(50) not null,
G# varchar(50),
primary key (ssn),
unique(name, ssn, G#))

create table Professor
(
name varchar(50),
ssn varchar(50) not null,
G# varchar(50),
teach_record varchar(50),
primary key (ssn),
unique (ssn, G#),
foreign key (name, ssn, G#) references People(name, ssn, G#) ON DELETE CASCADE
)

create table Student
(
name varchar(50),
ssn varchar(50) not null,
G# varchar(50),
primary key (ssn),
unique (ssn, G#),
foreign key (name, ssn, G#) references People(name, ssn, G#) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

This is the non GTA

```
create table NonGTA
(
name varchar(50),
ssn varchar(50) not null,
G# varchar(50),
primary key (ssn),
unique (ssn, G#),
foreign key (name, ssn, G#) references Student(name, ssn, G#) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Comment: What does "G#" mean? (Your table structure seems incomplete for what you're trying to do.)

Comment: It is a sort of ID, these tables model after my school system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you, your GTA and NonGTA tables should reference the student table. I understand that GTA and NonGTA have something to do with students, and they have nothing to do with professors or any other kind of person.

But a foreign key has to reference a set of columns that is declared to be either PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE. The foreign key you're trying to declare in NonGTA can't reference {name, ssn, G#}, because there's no suitable constraint on that set of columns. Reference {ssn} or {ssn, G#} instead.

---

**Other possible issues**

If G# is supposed to be unique, then People.G# should be declared UNIQUE. It might need to be declared NOT NULL, too.

Think twice about including extra, unnecessary columns in your UNIQUE constraints. There's *probably* no good reason to include "name" in a UNIQUE constraint. (Especially since you can't easily correct misspellings--Oracle doesn't support ON UPDATE CASCADE.)

Comment: I see, so that is why. Thank you sir.

Comment: Other things for you to think about. Also, on SO, upvote all the good answers, accept the best answer, and wait a couple of days for others to respond before you accept an answer.